# Speed Up Calculating Returns

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python 2.7. I am looking to calculate compounding returns from daily returns and my current code is pretty slow at calculating returns, so I was looking for areas where I could gain efficiency.

What I want to do is pass two dates and a security into a price table and calulate the compounding returns between those dates using the giving security.

I have a price table (`prices_df`):

```
security_id px_last    asof
    1       3.055   2015-01-05
    1       3.360   2015-01-06
    1       3.315   2015-01-07
    1       3.245   2015-01-08
    1       3.185   2015-01-09
```

I also have a table with two dates and security (`events_df`):

```
asof            disclosed_on    security_ref_id
2015-01-05  2015-01-09 16:31:00     1
2018-03-22  2018-03-27 16:33:00     3616
2017-08-03  2018-03-27 12:13:00     2591
2018-03-22  2018-03-27 11:33:00     3615
2018-03-22  2018-03-27 10:51:00     3615
```

Using the two dates in this table, I want to use the price table to calculate the returns.

The two functions I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
# compounds returns
def cum_rtrn(df):
    df_out = df.add(1).cumprod()
    df_out['return'].iat[0] = 1
    return df_out

# calculates compound returns from prices between two dates
def calc_comp_returns(price_df, start_date=None, end_date=None, security=None):
    df = price_df[price_df.security_id == security]
    df = df.set_index(['asof'])
    df = df.loc[start_date:end_date]
    df['return'] = df.px_last.pct_change()
    df = df[['return']]
    df = cum_rtrn(df)
    return df.iloc[-1][0]
```

I then iterate over the `events_df` with `.iterrows` passng the `calc_comp_returns` function each time. However, this is a very slow process as I have 10K+ iterations, so I am looking for improvements. Solution does not need to be based in `pandas`

```
# example of how function is called
start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-01-05', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-01-09', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
calc_comp_returns(prices_df, start_date=start, end_date=end, security=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (100x times faster on my computer with some dummy data).

```
import numpy as np

price_df = price_df.set_index('asof')

def calc_comp_returns_fast(price_df, start_date, end_date, security):
    rows = price_df[price_df.security_id == security].loc[start_date:end_date]
    changes = rows.px_last.pct_change()
    comp_rtrn = np.prod(changes + 1)
    return comp_rtrn
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
 def calc_comp_returns_fast(price_df, start_date, end_date, security):
    return np.prod(price_df[price_df.security_id == security].loc[start_date:end_date].px_last.pct_change() + 1)
```

Not that I call the `set_index` method beforehand, it only needs to be done once on the entire `price_df` dataframe.

It is faster because it does not recreate DataFrames at each step. In your code, `df` is overwritten almost at each line by a new dataframe. Both the init process and the garbage collection (erasing unused data from memory) take a lot of time.

In my code, `rows` is a slice or a "view" of the original data, it does not need to copy or re-init any object. Also, I used directly the numpy product function, which is the same as taking the last cumprod element (pandas uses `np.cumprod` internally anyway).

Suggestion : if you are using IPython, Jupyter or Spyder, you can use the magic `%prun calc_comp_returns(...)` to see which part takes the most time. I ran it on your code, and it was the garbage collector, using like more than 50% of the total running time!

Comment: Never knew about the `%prun` magic function. That is really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with pandas, but I'll give this a shot.

## Problem with your solution

Your solution currently does a huge amount of unnecessary calculation. This is mostly due to the line:

```
    df['return'] = df.px_last.pct_change()
```

This line is actually calcuating the percent change for *every* date between start and end. Just fixing this issue should give you a huge speed up. You should just get the start price and the end price and compare the two. The prices inbetween these two prices are completely irrelevant to your calculations. Again, my familiarity with pandas is nil, but you should do something like this instead:

```
def calc_comp_returns(price_df, start_date=None, end_date=None, security=None):
    df = price_df[price_df.security_id == security]
    df = df.set_index(['asof'])
    df = df.loc[start_date:end_date]
    return 1 + (df['px_last'].iloc(-1) - df['px_last'].iloc(0)
```

Remember that this code relies on the fact that price_df is sorted by date, so be careful to make sure you only pass `calc_comp_returns` a date-sorted price_df.

Answer (score 0):

We'll use `pd.merge_asof` to grab prices from `prices_df`.  However, when we do, we'll need to have relevant dataframes sorted by the date columns we are utilizing.  Also, for convenience, I'll aggregate some `pd.merge_asof` parameters in dictionaries to be used as keyword arguments.

```
prices_df = prices_df.sort_values(['asof'])

aed = events_df.sort_values('asof')
ded = events_df.sort_values('disclosed_on')

aokw = dict(
    left_on='asof', right_on='asof',
    left_by='security_ref_id', right_by='security_id'
)

start_price = pd.merge_asof(aed, prices_df, **aokw).px_last

dokw = dict(
    left_on='disclosed_on', right_on='asof',
    left_by='security_ref_id', right_by='security_id'
)

end_price = pd.merge_asof(ded, prices_df, **dokw).px_last

returns = end_price.div(start_price).sub(1).rename('return')
events_df.join(returns)

        asof        disclosed_on  security_ref_id    return
0 2015-01-05 2015-01-09 16:31:00                1  0.040816
1 2018-03-22 2018-03-27 16:33:00             3616       NaN
2 2017-08-03 2018-03-27 12:13:00             2591       NaN
3 2018-03-22 2018-03-27 11:33:00             3615       NaN
4 2018-03-22 2018-03-27 10:51:00             3615       NaN
```